# npm run <script-name> is not working

Tags: npm

I've defined scripts in my `package.json` like this:

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "webpack",
  "start": "webpack-dev-server --inline --hot --host 0.0.0.0"
},
```

I have problems running them. When i try `npm run start`or `npm run build` I always get:

```
Lifecycle scripts included in iski.world:
  start
    webpack-dev-server --inline --hot --host 0.0.0.0

available via `npm run-script`:
  build
    webpack
```

However running `npm start` works.

Node version: 5.1.0
npm version: 3.3.12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it by completely reinstalling node/nvm on my system after I encountered various other weird issues. I still have no idea what the problem was.